# How to prevent default ID for textboxes in Struts2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am creating and filling a text-boxes from an arraylist using struts iterator. Now all the generated text-boxes have same "ID", even if didn't give id for each element. I want either the ID's to be unique or no ID's at all.

```
<s:iterator value="specificationList" status="status">
    <s:textfield name="specification" />                            
</s:iterator>
```

**Expected output**

```
<input type="text" value="Test Spec1" name="specification">
<input type="text" value="Test Spec2" name="specification">
<input type="text" value="Test Spec3" name="specification">
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="specification1" value="Test Spec1" name="specification">
<input type="text" id="specification2" value="Test Spec2" name="specification">
<input type="text" id="specification3" value="Test Spec3" name="specification">
```

**Actual Output**

```
<input type="text" id="specification" value="Test Spec1" name="specification">
<input type="text" id="specification" value="Test Spec2" name="specification">
<input type="text" id="specification" value="Test Spec3" name="specification">
```

I also tried s:form themes simple and css_xhtml all these creating id's for the text-boxes

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it an id.

(Untested, but close; off the top of my head.)

```xml
<s:iterator value="specificationList" status="status">
  <s:textfield name="specification" id="%{#status.count}" />
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: If i give it ID, it will be same for all the text-boxes. I want each to have unique ids.

Comment: @Hasif Then give each one a unique ID--the `id` attribute is dynamic; use OGNL. I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: how to give Id dynamically. I tried
`<s:textfield id="${status.count}" name="specification" />`
I get the error **"attribute id does not accept any expressions"**

Comment: @Hasif Because you're using JSP EL, not OGNL.

Comment: @Hasif I'd recommend reading the S2 documentation if it's the framework you're using.